# background-image transition not working on form button

Tags: html, css, css-transitions, transition

I have a simple form like this:

```
<section class="subscribe" title='Lorem Ipsum'>
    <form class="form-wrapper cf" method="post">
        <input class="tiptipNewsletterInfo" id="emailInputText" name="email" placeholder="Enter your email here..." />
        <button class="showforDesktopsOnly" id="submitBtnForDesktop" type="submit">Subscribe</button>
    </form>
</section>
```

Now, I want to change the background image being displayed on the submit button when the mouse hovers over it. For this I've tried using the following CSS, but its not working:

```
.form-wrapper #submitBtnForDesktop {
    background: url("http://i.imgur.com/ANkUR4e.png") no-repeat 0 0 transparent;
    transition: background-image 0.5s;
}

.form-wrapper #submitBtnForDesktop:hover {
    background: url("http://i.imgur.com/ANkUR4e.png") no-repeat 0 -28px transparent;
}
```

I am currently using `transition: background-image 0.5s;` elsewhere to change other background images on mouse hover, but it's just not working in this case.

Anyone know why ?

JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/ahmadka/49nzM/

Answer (score 0):

css3 transitions only work on numeric and (in some browser) color hex values, but not on image backgrounds as you are trying to do

to achieve the "fade from one image to another" that you want, you'll need to change your html&css;

html

```
....
<button class="showforDesktopsOnly" id="submitBtnForDesktop" type="submit">
    <div class="hax"></div>
    Subscribe
</button>
....
```

css

```
....
#submitBtnForDesktop .hax{
    width:100%;
    height:100%;
    background: url("http://i.imgur.com/ANkUR4e.png") no-repeat 0 0 transparent;
    transition: opacity 0.5s;
    opacity:1
}
#submitBtnForDesktop:hover .hax{
    opacity:0
}
....
```

Comment: If I change it to `background-position`, there is a transition, but not the fade transition I wanted. Instead one image moves 'out' vertically, and another 'moves in'

Comment: I'm guessing splitting the image into 2 might work for me, but I want to avoid that as I intend to use sprites.

Comment: I know.. thats also what your css tells the browser to do.
if you want to fade, you can achieve that with a sprite, but you will need 2 stacked elements where one does a opacity:0 in the :hover class (with transition set to opacity)